# Message returned as undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I tried to send notifications through firebase functions when data is stored in my firebase database. It sends the message alright but a log tag I added to see if it got the name of the file that was uploaded to my firebase database came back as "Lecture note uploaded is: **undefined**". That's **line 12** I don't understand why. 
Below is my code.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Lecture_Materials/{MIS}/{MISId}/name')
.onWrite(( change,context) =>{

// Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
var eventSnapshot = change.after.val();
var str1 = "Lecture material uploaded is: " + eventSnapshot.name;
console.log(str1);

var topic = "Management.Information.System";
var payload = {
    data: {
        name: str1,
    }
};

// Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload)
    .then(function (response) {
        // See the MessagingTopicResponse reference documentation for the
        // contents of response.
        console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        return;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
    });
    });
```

[image: Check out the functions LOGS interface please.]

Comment: *"I don't understand why"* - it's because `eventSnapshot.name` is `undefined` - try `console.log(eventSnapshot)` to see what you are dealing with

Comment: Okay thanks for that Jaromanda. But the message still failed to be sent. I didn't receive a notification from the function being fired. What could be wrong

Comment: so, do you get `"Successfully sent message:"` or `"Error sending message:"` ( I see the former in your log)

Comment: Yes please. It does read "Successfully sent message". But the notification doesn't show on my phone.

Comment: what phone? there's a phone now?

Comment: maybe because the billing account messages in that picture you posted? did you think that may be an issue?

Comment: Huh? I use the function to send notifications to my android app when that function is fired. Please read the description for better understanding.

Comment: I actually have no idea please.

Comment: `Please read the description for better understanding` - nowhere in the description does it mention anything about android app - so, I guess I didn't read your mind well enough. `I actually have no idea please` that makes two of us - I merely suggested something about the **only** question you actually asked which was `Lecture note uploaded is: undefined". That's line 12 I don't understand why` - not sure how I was meant to instinctively *know* that there's an android app involved, and your phone isn't receiving messages!! Perhaps you should write those things in the question

Comment: My guess is that "Billing account not configured. **External network is not accessible ...** etc" is the reason your phone isn't receiving any messages. Seems almost obvious

Comment: okay thNKS for that

Comment: @JaromandaX The warning about a billing account is purely informational here. As far as I can see, this code won't need one.

Comment: @UpwardStudios The error message you posted is slightly different from the message that this code logs. Are you sure this is the code causing the problem? If you are, what was the logging output when you did `console.log(eventSnapshot)` as Jaromanda X suggested?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - really? so, you think lack of billing information is not the reason the OP is getting messages on his phone?

Comment: Also, there is no **error** message at all - the **message** is `Lecture material uploaded is: undefined` ... ***exactly*** the same as what's in the picture of the log

Comment: @JaromandaX Neh, that message is (unfortunately) shown to all users without a billing account. It only actually causes problems if the code calls 3rd party APIs. Since OP only calls Firebase Cloud Messaging (as far as I can see), the message is a harmless red herring. :-/

Comment: OK. So the "Lecture note uploaded is: undefined" message in your question is just a copy/paste mistake then? Cool, please update and we can move on. What is the logging output that Jaromanda X requested in his first comment?

Comment: Hello Frank. The output was successful and the message was successfully logged as sent. But still I didn't receive the notification. What could be the problem? Could it be from my android codes?